# Head Bolt Sequence - 2004 Chevy 4.3L V6 S10

Tags: chevrolet, head-gasket

I am trying to find the head bolt sequence for a 2004 Chevy 4.3L V6 S10 truck.  I have managed to find the torque specs but the site I found them on does not list the order they should be removed or installed.  The only site that has mentioned anything about order is ehow.com, but the page was generic for 4.3L engines instead of specific to my make and model, which makes me nervous.  As I understand it, there should be a very specific order the head bolts need to be removed and replaced in.


The site I found the torque specs on: [Link](http://www.torkspec.com/torkspecme.aspx?KI=12-4.3L-262ci-V6) 
The site I found a sequence on but am unsure about: [Link](http://www.ehow.com/facts_8008937_tightening-sequence-43-engine.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the sequence

[image]

Preferred Method is as follows

- All bolts first sequence 22 ft. lbs.
- Long Bolt Final Pass in Sequence 75 degrees
- Medium Bolt Final Pass in Sequence 65 degrees
- Short Bolt Final Pass in Sequence 55 degrees

Optional Method

- First Pass in Sequence 26 ft. lbs.
- Second Pass in Sequence 44 ft. lbs.
- Final Pass in Sequence 66 ft. lbs.

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  Mind if I ask where you found it.

Comment: @gSamp ... these are **torque-to-yield bolts**. Ensure you are using NEW bolts when you put things back together, as the old (original) ones only have one use in them.

Comment: @Paulster2 Thank you for that, I had already decided to replace the bolts since we were going to have it open anyway.  Nice to know that was a good decision.

Comment: @Paulster2 These are not required to be replaced, they **can** be reused.

Comment: @gSamp That engine as been around for a while and the diagram can be found online in many places including forums. Auto Zone has free service information as well. I did look up the specs in a manual to confirm they were correct.

Comment: @Larry ... All newer head bolts used by GM are T2Y bolts. One use only. They must be replaced or will result in head gasket failure.

Comment: @Paulster2 Will have to agree to disagree. I double checked the GM service manual, the bolts can be reused per GM. I am familiar with the torque to yield bolts that have to be replaced, but again the GM service manual says otherwise in this specific application

Comment: @Larry ... If you have the GM Service Manual, I will go with what you are saying. I am assuming they are T2Y since GM has been using them since the mid-90s. In this case, I would err on the side of caution. These head bolts are CHEAP and easy to get, so replacing them is not a bad or hard thing to do. If a building goes with ARP bolts or studs, they would never have to worry about it again.

Answer (score 0):

The general consensus when tourqueing is to use a pattern that will flatten from the middle to the outside edges allowing a complete flat seal and equal pressure which will assist in straightening any small warping that may be present